# How can I unit test anonymous callbacks passed to JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm creating a jQuery UI autocomplete widget passing in a callback function, like this:

```
input.autocomplete( {
    ...,
    select: function ( event, ui ) {
        valueField.val( ui.item.id );
    },
    ...
} );
```

How can I unit test the `select` function to assert that when it's called the `valueField` is updated with the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [JsMockito](http://jsmockito.org/) you can capture the parameter passed in to the `autocomplete` function, eg:

```
var params;
when( input ).autocomplete().then( function ( p ) {
    params = p;
} );
```

By doing this you're saving the reference to the anonymous function, so you can call it later.

```
params.select( null, { item: { id: someId } } );
verify( valueField ).val( someId );
```

This technique can also be used for functions that are private, for example, when using the [module pattern](http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern).

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to unit test your javascript, the best plan is to create first class functions for your callbacks.

Comment: That would work, but then you lose the advantage of private or anonymous functions.

Comment: Very true. You get to decide which is more important to you.